# Why can I not alter the value of shape_amount?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to find a solution to add 1 to the value of `shape_amount` within a different class and return the value back to compare it.

This is the first class that compares the value of shape_amount.

```
class BEGIN_DRAWING:
    def begin_draw(run, shape_opt, color_value, color):
        global shape_amount
        shape_amount = 0
        i = True
        while i == True:
            color = color_value(color)
            run.movement(shape_amount, color)
            print(shape_amount)
            if shape_amount == shape_opt:
                i = False
        run.movement(shape_amount, color)
```

I print `shape_amount` to check its values but outputs 0

```
class DRAWING_CURVED:
    def fill(shape_amount, color):
        rand_int = randint(0, 20)
        if rand_int == 0:
            end_fill()
            fillcolor(color)
            begin_fill()
            shape_amount += 1
            return shape_amount
```

This is supposed to add 1 to the value of `shape_amount` every time a shape is filled but it does not seem to be doing so.

Comment: just a suggestion but convention for classes in python is title case, like `BeginDrewing`

Comment: Will change thank you

Comment: In your second block of code, `shape_amount` is a local variable; it's completely unrelated to the global variable with the same name (even if they happen to have the same value).  Assigning to a local variable has no effect outside of the function.

Comment: Oh I had not thought about it not accessing the global

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are passing the `shape_amount` global variable into a function as a parameter. This parameter will not be treated as the global variable, but as a normal parameter.

The below highlights this, it prints for me:
2
1
2

```py
def test():
    global x
    x = 1
    val = increment(x)
    print(val)
    print(x)
    increment_two()
    print(x)

def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def increment_two():
    global x
    x += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot problem is now solved